# Migrate Kafka Streams code to Spring Cloud Stream?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

Will the Spring cloud stream support the below Kafka Streams application. 
Below is code in excerpt of the Kafka sample app. Any feedback or support is appreciated.

```
        ...
        StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();

        KStream<String, Purchase> purchaseKStream = streamsBuilder.stream.....
        KStream<String, PurchasePattern> patternKStream = purchaseKStream.mapValues...
        patternKStream.print(Printed.<String, PurchasePattern>toSysOut().withLabel("patterns"));
        patternKStream.to("patterns", Produced.with(stringSerde, purchasePatternSerde));
        purchaseKStream.print(Printed.<String, Purchase>toSysOut().withLabel("purchases"));
        purchaseKStream.to("purchases", Produced.with(stringSerde, purchaseSerde));

        // adding State to processor
        String rewardsStateStoreName = "rewardsPointsStore";
        RewardsStreamPartitioner streamPartitioner = new RewardsStreamPartitioner();
        KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier storeSupplier = Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore(rewardsStateStoreName);
        StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, Integer>> storeBuilder = Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(storeSupplier.....
        streamsBuilder.addStateStore(storeBuilder);
        KStream<String, Purchase> transByCustomerStream = purchaseKStream.through("customer_transactions",....
        KStream<String, RewardAccumulator> statefulRewardAccumulator = transByCustomerStream
                .transformValues(() -> new PurchaseRewardTransformer(rewardsStateStoreName), rewardsStateStoreName);
        statefulRewardAccumulator.print(Printed.<String, RewardAccumulator>toSysOut().withLabel("stateful-rewards"));
        statefulRewardAccumulator.to("rewards", Produced.with(stringSerde, rewardAccumulatorSerde));

        KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(streamsBuilder.build(), getProperties());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Spring Cloud Stream `Horsham (3.0.0)` release, the following pseudo-code should work. I didn't test this code, but this should work with the right configuration for the destination, etc. Please take a look at the [docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/3.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_kafka_streams_binder) for that.

```
@SpringBootApplicaiton
public class SampleApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
   SpringApplication.run(SampleApp.class, args);
  }

   @Bean
   public Function<KStream<String, Purchase>, KStream<String, RewardAccumulator>> process() {
     return purchaseKStream -> {
           purchaseKStream.print(Printed.<String, Purchase>toSysOut().withLabel("purchases"));
           KStream<String, PurchasePattern> patternKStream = purchaseKStream.mapValues...
           patternKStream.print(Printed.<String, PurchasePattern>toSysOut().withLabel("patterns"));
           patternKStream.to("patterns", Produced.with(stringSerde, purchasePatternSerde));
                purchaseKStream.to("purchases", Produced.with(stringSerde, purchaseSerde));

           KStream<String, Purchase> transByCustomerStream = purchaseKStream.through("customer_transactions",....
           KStream<String, RewardAccumulator> statefulRewardAccumulator = transByCustomerStream.transformValues(()
                statefulRewardAccumulator.print(Printed.<String, RewardAccumulator>toSysOut().withLabel("stateful-rewards"));

           return statefulRewardAccumulator;
       }        
   }

   @Bean
   public StoreBuilder storeBuilder() {
     String rewardsStateStoreName = "rewardsPointsStore";
     RewardsStreamPartitioner streamPartitioner = new RewardsStreamPartitioner();
     KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier storeSupplier = Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore(rewardsStateStoreName);
     StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, Integer>> storeBuilder = Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(storeSupplier.....
     return storeBuilder;
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you @sobychacko, appreciate your active support in the community.

Comment: Hi @sobychacko, in the code above, the storeBuilder() method is not referenced in the function, was the method just for info?

Comment: How is that state store being used in your original code?

Comment: The state is being stored in **PurchaseRewardTransformer** class, below is the method. 

`public RewardAccumulator transform(Purchase value) {
 RewardAccumulator rewardAccumulator = RewardAccumulator.builder(value).build();
 Integer accumulatedSoFar = stateStore.get(rewardAccumulator.getCustomerId());
    if (accumulatedSoFar != null) {
            rewardAccumulator.addRewardPoints(accumulatedSoFar);
    }
    stateStore.put(rewardAccumulator.getCustomerId(), rewardAccumulator.getTotalRewardPoints());
    return rewardAccumulator;
}`

Comment: I have edited the original question to provide more clarity regarding the store.